# How to change an Imagebutton to an integer

Tags: java, android, imagebutton

basically I am trying to make a side scrolling game, with an an Image button, the reason why I am using the image button is because when the image of the person is clicked it double jumps, when the background is clicked, it jumps.  but, I am getting a problem when trying to convert an imagebutton into an integer, how would I go about doing this? or is there a better way of doing things such as double clicking the background for a double jump ect.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are much, much better ways to go about this. It would take a lot of unnecessary work to get your implementation to work correctly. What you want to do is draw an image on a Canvas and check touch events and see if they happened in the boundary of that image.

Look here: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/07/android-game-development-displaying.html

Comment: I knew there was a better way, and I just couldn't think of it, Thank you. I will accept when it allows me